# Why does Python 3's tkinter importing syntax work in Python 2, but not with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x, pyinstaller

**TL; DR:** the first part of the title is answered simply below in the accepted answer (my own).  The second part, regarding `pyinstaller`, was never answered.

I don't recommend wasting your time reading the rest of this question and the many comments.

---

I am running Python 2.7 via Anaconda and do not have Python 3 installed as far as I know.  I'm confused about importing `tkinter`.  Several other questions here on Stack Overflow indicate that there are separate modules and slightly different importing syntax for `tkinter` depending on whether you are running Python 2 or Python 3.  However, the Python 3 syntax *sort of* works for me in Python 2 (see comments in code below).  What gives?

```
import sys
print sys.version
# prints: 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

# I hear these should not work in Python 2.  
# In reality, they work fine if run normally via the Python 2 interpreter.
# However, they do NOT work when I use pyinstaller to make an executable.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

# These work fine in Python 2, as they should, even if compiled into an exe.
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkMessageBox
```

**Edits:**

In response to Bryan Oakley's comment, the result of `print sys.path` is:

```
['C:\\Users\\...\\tkinter test program', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\lib', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\lib\\lib-tk', 
'C:\\Miniconda', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg']
```

In response to Sun Bear's answer, here's what happens on my computer:

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC
v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

In response to Łukasz Rogalski's comment:

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> print Tkinter.__file__
C:\Miniconda\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.pyc
>>> import tkinter
>>> print tkinter.__file__
C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\tkinter\__init__.pyc
>>>
```

In response to the discussion in the comments of Sun Bear's answer, this is the contents of `C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\tkinter\__init__.pyc`, which explains why `import tkinter` works even though I'm using Python 2:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
                      'Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder '
                      'or your installation of python-future is corrupted.')
```

Comment: Not working for me on macOS ("ImportError: No module named tkinter").

Comment: Non-case-sensitive filesystem on Windows, perhaps?  But a case-sensitive .zip archive when bundled into an executable...

Comment: I don't think it's a case insensitivity issue, because `ttk` and `messagebox` are only in `tkinter`, not `Tkinter`.  This fails: `from Tkinter import ttk`

Comment: By any change you have a file named `tkinter.py` in working directory?

Comment: Print out `sys.path`. Most likely, you have the location of python 3 libraries in your path.

Comment: @BryanOakley See my edit for the result of `print sys.path`.  I don't see anything that is obviously related to Python 3.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski No, I don't.

Comment: `print tkinter.__file__`, what is the output?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski See my edit.  I feel like we're getting somewhere now.  What do you make of it?  If tkinter is installed, how did it get there?  Did I get black-out drunk and start downloading Python 3 libraries one night?

Comment: Quoting from the discovered site package: "or your installation of python-future is corrupted." - i.e., the reason you were able to use the 3.x syntax in 2.x is *because you installed a third-party library (`python-future`) that is specifically designed to enable that sort of thing*. Voting to close as typo/not reproducible, as this question does not point at a meaningful problem.

Comment: " All I saw was the other branch being executed: from Tkinter import *" - yes; that's *because you had `python-future` installed and used 2.x*. It allowed you to use the 3.x syntax (as you said: "which explains why `import tkinter` works even though I'm using Python 2:" ) by creating a wrapper named `tkinter` (allowing use of the 3.x syntax) that imports `Tkinter` (wrapping the 2.x library). You saw the the `from Tkinter import *` branch executed because you used 2.x. I quoted the exception message from the other branch **because it indicates the name of what was installed** to make it work.

Comment: I assure you, I read the question and the supporting discussion very carefully. You asked why the 3.x syntax seemed to work in 2.x. The reason why the 3.x syntax seemed to work in 2.x, is because it actually did work. The reason it actually did work, is because of the third-party library named `python-future` that you installed. The purpose of this library is to make such things work. I know that it was `python-future` because I read the string literal in the `C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\tkinter\__init__.py` file that you posted.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 1) Ok, are you saying that installing python-future generates the file `C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\tkinter\__init__.py`?  I'm curious, how do you know that?  2) What about the other half of the mystery: why isn't this compatible with pyinstaller?

Comment: [That's expressly one of the purposes of `python-future `. `tkinter` is even one of the examples.](https://python-future.org/imports.html#standard-library-imports)

Comment: "I'm curious, how do you know that?" I inferred it from the context, but it's also [possible to look up the corresponding source code in the current version](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/master/src/tkinter/__init__.py). I knew, in any event, that this was not part of the standard library Tkinter implementation, because it is in `site-packages`. "why isn't this compatible with pyinstaller?" If you wanted to ask about that specifically, then you should have been explicit, and asked *one* question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1:** Why can a Python 2 interpreter execute this Python 3 code?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
```

**Answer:** (consolidated from my question updates and mine/others' comments) What makes it work is the module `python-future`.  Installing that module creates various "wrapper" files that do nothing but redirect Python 3 elements to their Python 2 counterparts: `tkinter` -> `Tkinter`, `tkinter.ttk` -> `ttk`, `tkinter.messagebox` -> `tkMessageBox`, etc.  That's one of the key purposes of the `python-future` module.

For example, here's `C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\tkinter\__init__.pyc`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
                      'Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder '
                      'or your installation of python-future is corrupted.')
```

**Issue 2:** Why does that same trick seem to be incompatible with the module `pyinstaller`?

**Answer:** I don't know.  No one here has discussed it, and I don't care to revisit it 6 years later myself.

Answer (score -2):

`tkinter` is a python 3 wrapper layer of Tk suited for Python 3 syntax.
`Tkinter` is a python 2 wrapper layer of Tk suited for Python 2 syntax.

import command is the same. But you need to import the correct wrapper for the type of python version you are using to write your code. Below shows **python 2 can only import** `Tkinter` **and not** `tkinter`.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter
>>> import Tkinter
>>>
```

**Update:** If Miniconda chooses to deviate from mainstream practice and does something behind the scene to allow what you have described, than it is done at the discretion of Miniconda. Your `print tkinter.__file__` command shows you have `tkinter` and `print Tkinter.__file__` command shows you have `Tkinter`. In short, Miniconda comes preloaded with both `Tkinter` and `tkinter`. Have you tried comparing these two files to see if they are identical or different?

Comment: This is not what happens on my computer.  See my edit.

Comment: @MarredCheese Can you locate your lib-tk folder and see if both tkinter.py and Tkinter.py are there?  Also open these file and compare their syntax.

Comment: I have two lib-tk folders, but both just have Tkinter.py inside of them, not tkinter.py.  One is in `C:\Miniconda\Lib`, and the other is in `C:\Miniconda\pkgs\python-2.7.12-0\Lib`.

Comment: @MarredCheese This means you are using Tkinter. I suspect Miniconda somewhere has a script to equate tkinter as Tkinter.... Agree?

Comment: `from Tkinter import ttk` fails, whereas `from tkinter import ttk` works.  Since ttk is part of tkinter but not Tkinter, this does not support the idea that `import tkinter` is secretly importing `Tkinter` behind the scenes.

Comment: @MarredCheese I did not say tkinter is secretly importing Tkinter. I am questioning if Miniconda is doing something behind the scene. In any case, I am saying that since you only have Tkinter in your lib-tk and not tkinter, your system can only run Tkinter which is specific to python2. Corrections to your recent comment. 1. ttk is available in both Tkinter and tkinter not just tkinter. 2. You wrote "These work fine in Python 2" in your question. Now you say Tkinter can't import ttk. These two statement contradicts each other.

Comment: @MarredCheese I just noticed your print tkinter.__file__ shows you have tkinter. In short, Miniconda is preloaded with Tkinter and tkinter. Have you tried comparing these two files to see if they are identical or different?

Comment: No, ttk is not part of Tkinter, and I never said it was, so there's no contradiction. 1)  `import ttk` works for me and should work in Python 2.  2) `from Tkinter import ttk` does not work for me and should not work since ttk is not part of Tkinter.  3) `from tkinter import ttk` does work for me and should work in Python 3 since ttk is part of tkinter.  However, I saw your second comment and looked inside the files as you suggested, and it turns out you were right about miniconda.  I'll post an edit showing more detail.  Want to update your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @MarredCheese. Look forward to reading your findings. I've updated my answered.

Comment: I already put up the edit I'm talking about.  When I run `import tkinter`, it calls the `__init__.py` file that I pasted into my question.  As you can see in that file's code, all it does is ignore my request to import tkinter and instead import Tkinter.  So Python 2 Miniconda doesn't come with the real tkinter library.  Instead, it comes with a fake tkinter library - a series of hollow tkinter files that do nothing but redirect to their Tkinter counterparts.  tkinter --> Tkinter, tkinter.ttk --> ttk, tkninter.messagebox --> tkMessageBox, etc.